# Building Visual Studio Deployment Project (.vdproj) through the command line

Tags: build-automation, deployment-project

I have a deployment project deployment.vdproj to which I have added the project output of project.csproj. I want to build deployment.vdproj through the command line. But while doing so I need to specify a property (/p:) for project.csproj. How do I this?

I have used devenv.com to build deployment.vdproj, but I cannot figure out how to pass in the property for project.csproj

The command line I used is:

```
        devenv.exe /build Debug deployment.vdproj
```

This works fine. But I want to specify the output path of project.csproj as well. Something like /p:OutputPath="C:\output". Is it possible to control the properties of project.csproj while building deployment.vdproj? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csproj already contains the output path, so I don't think you can modify using command line parameter. I guess the only way is to modify the csproj using regular expression say command line perl -i .... *.csproj and then run the MSBuild and revert again the changes in the csproj.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Though I don't think that will solve my problem! I need to redirect the output of the csproj. If I use msbuild to build it with the desired property, and then use devenv.com to build the vdproj, it will go ahead and again build the csproj without the desired property value. Therefore the output of the csproj will again be in an undesired location. msbuild does not support building of vdproj as I know. Thats why I want to know if there is any way I can pass that as a command line parameter to devenv.com.